# Rails: Scheduled Job not Running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I'm using the [Whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) with my Rails 3.2 app on an Ubuntu server.  I have a monthly job that I want to run on the first day of the month, but it didn't seem to work.

I know that the code works because I ran it from the console on the server when I found it didn't run.  I have other jobs that run more frequently (hourly, daily), but this one didn't run.  Can someone please help me determine what I did wrong?

```
# schedule.rb
every 1.month, :at => "beginning of the month at 3am" do
  rake "users:update_monthly"
end

# lib/schedule.rake
namespace :users do

  task :update_monthly => :environment do
    User.update_monthly
  end

end
```

When I run `crontab -l` on the server:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: whenever_schedule
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/articles

0 3 1 * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/deploy/foo/web_head/releases/20130801200106 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake users:update_monthly --silent'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: whenever_schedule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a Chronic parsing issue.

This might work:

```
every 1.month, :at => 'January 1st 3:00am' do
  rake "users:update_monthly"
end
```

Or this:

```
every 1.month, :at => 'start of the month at 9am' do
  rake "users:update_monthly"
end
```

It is tough because it looks like the crontab output on the server looks right.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess it's not a Whenever issue if Cron looks right.  I don't suppose Cron ever fails to trigger if the server is online?  I'm not sure how to test it if I even changed Whenever without waiting another month, especially since shorter durations already working for me.